# str_to_date returns null+mysql

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

When I am trying to convert varchar to date, I get Null values in return.

I have values as 05-MAR-2015 in my column.

I am running following query.

```
select STR_TO_DATE('n.Invoice_date','%d-%c-Y') from table n;
```

Once I run above query I get null values in return.

I want to introduce a new column in date format.

Comment: You forgot `%` before `Y` and the formattor should be `'%d-%b-%Y'`

Comment: What is your string format exactly in the column Invoice_date?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the literal string `'n.invoice_date'` is not a valid date. What you mean is:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(n.invoice_date, '%d-%b-%Y') FROM TABLE n
```

Comment: I tried to execute `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('05-MAR-2015','%d-%c-%Y');` on MYSQL but this does not work. Maybe it is no valid date?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes you are correct. DO I even need alias there?

Comment: The `n.` part can be omitted, yes.

Comment: This depends on your `invoice_date` field having a valid date in it. Do you get any errors? "Does not work" is perhaps the least useful description of a problem.

Comment: It simply returned null values. :(

Comment: Is `invoice_date` a `DATE` field, or is it something that follows the d-c-y format? Ideally you'd convert your `invoice_date` field to be a MySQL `DATE` column in the ISO YYYY-MM-DD format. That makes it possible to index, and do normal date calculations on it without conversion.

Comment: If you look carefully at the [date formatting options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you'll see `%c` is incorrect, what you want is `%b`. Please, next time **give some sample data** so others can recreate your problem instead of having to guess what you want. This saves a lot of frustration.

Comment: i guess he want `03` instead of `MAR` so `%c` is correct. The Datestring contains `MAR` so if he expacted to get this.. he dont need to create a Date out of the string... dont he ?

Comment: Thank you Tadman for your help. I am still learning MySQL and programming. I used following query and it worked.                                                            SELECT str_to_date(lower(Invoice_date),'%d-%b-%Y') from dw.spend_nordic;

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Good that you got it working. As a note, always keep the documentation open when you're working with databases. Even experienced developers need to check that they're calling the functions correctly. A quick check through it would have revealed this error earlier on. There's no shame in consulting reference material, that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in usage of `%c` instead of `%b` to get the date. You mixed the formatting of the date with the creation of a date value. This should do it:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(n.invoice_date,'%d-%b-%Y'), '%d-%c-%Y') FROM table n;
```

This results in: **05-3-2015**

Here you first create a date with `STR_TO_DATE` which must match the format in which it is stored in the field. Then you can format it with `DATE_FORMAT` in the way you want to.

See the MYSQL Docs for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I used following query -     SELECT str_to_date(lower(Invoice_date),'%d-%b-%Y') from dw.spend_nordic;